# Read special part in an line with Linux seed

Tags: linux, sed

I want to print only a special word from a special line.
My try:

```
check_rcon=$(eval sed '9!d' $HOME/test.cfg)
echo $check_rcon
```

Output:

```
rconpassword="CHANGE_ME"
```

Now he reads the hole line. I only need the input between " ". How can I solve that?

Comment: one solution i tryed:

eval grep rconpassword $HOME/test.cfg | cut -d'=' -d'"' -f2) <-- The output be right, but if there no possibility to work with seed?

Comment: How do you understand the role of `eval` in the `$(eval sed ...)` expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware of `grep -o`?

Imagine you are looking for a word in the text "123abc456", then you can do:

```
echo "123abc456" | grep -o "[a-z]*"
```

This returns `abc`.

The `grep` command means:

- A word only consists of letters, going from 'a' to 'z' (hence `[a-z]`).
- As only that word needs to be returned (omit all the rest), use the `-o` switch.